# java.io.FileNotFoundException for jbehave/storyDurations.props

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jbehave

I'm trying to get jBehave working on my 2-module Google App Engine project modeled after https://github.com/ctesniere/appengine-modules-sample-java.  I generated the jBehave archetype (`jbehave-simple-archetype`) using Maven.  I was able to get this to run successfully.

However, when I manually applied the changes to my pom.xml on my target project and copied over the two java files generated by the jBehave archetype, I could not get a successful `mvn clean install`.

I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- jbehave-maven-plugin:3.9.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) @ followerdownloader-frontend ---
[INFO] Running stories as embeddables using embedder Embedder[storyMapper=StoryMapper,storyRunner=StoryRunner,embedderMonitor=MavenEmbedderMonitor,classLoader=EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/classes/, appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.17.jar, servlet-api-2.5.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, jbehave-core-3.9.5.jar, hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar, freemarker-2.3.19.jar, paranamer-2.4.jar, xstream-1.4.5.jar, xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar],parent=ClassRealm[plugin>org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.9.5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6da21389]],embedderControls=UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]],embedderFailureStrategy=<null>,configuration=org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration@3ba4236f,candidateSteps=<null>,stepsFactory=<null>,metaFilters=[],systemProperties=<null>,executorService=<null>,executorServiceCreated=false,storyManager=<null>]
[INFO] Found class names: [com.netbase.jbehaveexample.MyStories]
[INFO] Using controls UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]]
[INFO] Running embeddable com.netbase.jbehaveexample.MyStories
[INFO] Processing system properties {}
[INFO] Using controls UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]]

(BeforeStories)


(AfterStories)

[INFO] Generating reports view to '/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, txt, html, xml]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/jbehave/storyDurations.props (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.TemplateableViewGenerator.storyDurations(TemplateableViewGenerator.java:123)
    at org.jbehave.core.reporters.TemplateableViewGenerator.generateReportsView(TemplateableViewGenerator.java:115)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:249)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:237)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:213)
    at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.run(JUnitStories.java:20)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runAsEmbeddables(Embedder.java:121)
    at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.execute(RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.java:18)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios (of which 0 pending)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ followerdownloader-frontend ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.war to /Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/netbase/followerdownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/1.0/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.war
[INFO] Installing /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/pom.xml to /Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/netbase/followerdownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/1.0/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.363 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-22T14:53:51-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I cannot find a file named `behave/storyDurations.props` to copy over from the archetype build to my own project.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that was missing to be copied over from the archetype to the new project was `stories/my.story`.  Even though the error is about something else, I was able to get this error to go away when I copied over the my.story file:

```
[INFO] --- jbehave-maven-plugin:3.9.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) @ followerdownloader-frontend ---
[INFO] Running stories as embeddables using embedder Embedder[storyMapper=StoryMapper,storyRunner=StoryRunner,embedderMonitor=MavenEmbedderMonitor,classLoader=EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/classes/, appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.17.jar, servlet-api-2.5.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, jbehave-core-3.9.5.jar, hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar, commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, commons-io-2.4.jar, commons-lang-2.6.jar, plexus-utils-3.0.10.jar, freemarker-2.3.19.jar, paranamer-2.4.jar, xstream-1.4.5.jar, xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar],parent=ClassRealm[plugin>org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.9.5, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6da21389]],embedderControls=UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]],embedderFailureStrategy=<null>,configuration=org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration@2b37d486,candidateSteps=<null>,stepsFactory=<null>,metaFilters=[],systemProperties=<null>,executorService=<null>,executorServiceCreated=false,storyManager=<null>]
[INFO] Found class names: [com.netbase.jbehaveexample.MyStories]
[INFO] Using controls UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]]
[INFO] Running embeddable com.netbase.jbehaveexample.MyStories
[INFO] Processing system properties {}
[INFO] Using controls UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories=true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=false,verboseFailures=false,verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=300,failOnStoryTimeout=false,threads=1]]

(BeforeStories)

[INFO] Running story com/netbase/jbehaveexample/stories/my.story

(com/netbase/jbehaveexample/stories/my.story)
Scenario: A scenario with some pending steps
Given I am a pending step (PENDING)
And I am still pending step (PENDING)
When a good soul will implement me (PENDING)
Then I shall be happy (PENDING)
@Given("I am a pending step")
@Pending
public void givenIAmAPendingStep() {
  // PENDING
}

@Given("I am still pending step")
@Pending
public void givenIAmStillPendingStep() {
  // PENDING
}

@When("a good soul will implement me")
@Pending
public void whenAGoodSoulWillImplementMe() {
  // PENDING
}

@Then("I shall be happy")
@Pending
public void thenIShallBeHappy() {
  // PENDING
}




(AfterStories)

[INFO] Generating reports view to '/Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/jbehave' using formats '[stats, console, txt, html, xml]' and view properties '{navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl}'
[INFO] Reports view generated with 1 stories (of which 1 pending) containing 1 scenarios (of which 1 pending)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ followerdownloader-frontend ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/target/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.war to /Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/netbase/followerdownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/1.0/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.war
[INFO] Installing /Users/mosofsky/Developer/FollowerDownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/pom.xml to /Users/mosofsky/.m2/repository/com/netbase/followerdownloader/followerdownloader-frontend/1.0/followerdownloader-frontend-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.486 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-22T15:08:01-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/229M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Copying over the .story file made the java.io.FileNotFoundException for jbehave/storyDurations.props error go away.

=================

UPDATE: Another solution is to make a symbolic link to the directory containing the story files.  This is useful if you have multiple Google App Engine modules but you want to share the story files across the modules.  For an explanation on how to set up the symbolic link ("symlink"), see this other solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28137844/2848676

Comment: I ran into this again and once again the solution was to make sure I had at least one .story file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many ways, but still didn't solved my issue. Finally I removed spaces and wildcard characters from my path(including folder names), then its allowed me to execute Test Runner

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by -

1. List item Adding the instance of the step class like `new ClassnameSteps()` in `StoryRunner.java`.
2. I used `<story>Classname</story>` instead of `<Story>Classname</Story>`. Do mind the small **s** & capital **S** in story.